# Combine multiple routes into one serverless function in Vercel using Python?

Tags: python, vercel, sanic

I currently have a Nextjs app with python api backend. The problem I am running into is that Vercel has a limit of 24 Serverless functions and they seem to recommend that one should combine your serverless functions to "optimize" your functions and avoid cold starts.

Currently I have the following code

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json
app = Sanic()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
async def index(request, path=""):
    return json({'hello': path})

@app.route('/other_route')
async def other_route(request, path=""):
    return json({'whatever': path})
```

However when I hit `api/other_route` I get a 404. I know that I can create separate file called `other_route.py` But I was wondering if there was a way to combine that route in my `index.py` route to avoid creating another serverless function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a vercel config in your project root `vercel.json`

```
{
    "routes": [{
        "src": "/api/(.*)",
        "dest": "api/index.py"
    }]
}
```

This routes all requests to `/` which is the Sanic instance. Sanic then knows how to route to the handler. You should also change your path arg in `other_route` method to be `path="other_route"`

Comment: Routing to "src": "/(.*)" overwrites Nextjs routing, which is not what one would want to do. Should route to only /api routes. I tried changing source to "src": "/api/(.*)", but that doesnt work

Comment: Oh yes I should have included that. My project is using vercel exclusively for functions not SSG, so this works for my use case